# how to create the executable jar file for cucumber project with serenity-gradle -not maven project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber, serenity-bdd

i want to create the executable jar file for my project as like we do for other java project.
i am using intellij IDE.
by using cucumber & serenity-gradle i had created by automation test scripts.
do not have the main(String []args) method.
kindly suggest.

I had tried all the plugins,but non of them worked for.

this is my build.gradle

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

defaultTasks 'clean', 'test', 'serenity:aggregate'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.serenity-bdd:serenity-gradle-plugin:1.9.12")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.serenity-bdd', name: 'serenity-core', version: '1.9.12'
    compile group: 'net.serenity-bdd', name: 'serenity-cucumber', version: '1.9.5'
    compile group: 'net.serenity-bdd', name: 'serenity-junit', version: '1.9.12'
    compile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '3.4.0'

    test {
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        systemProperties System.getProperties()
        systemProperty 'logback.configurationFile', 'logback.xml'
    }
}
clean {
    delete 'target'
}
gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true
test.finalizedBy(aggregate)
```

below is the runner class from where i am running the feature files.

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"},
        glue = "com/ABC/WCB/stepdefs",
        features = "src/test/resources/features"
)

public class CucumberTest {

}
```

Comment: I do not have maven ,I am using cucumber & serenity-gradle.

Comment: please remove the duplicate tag